# Add line break between data in TD

Tags: php, html, html-table

Looking for a way to add a line break in between the text in TD. Which is always different. I'm guessing the detecting factor would be the space between.

```
<tr class="garment">

  <td>Garment:</td>

  <td>gildan white 4s  basic red 10m</td>

</tr>
```

This would be the result im looking for

```
  <td>Garment:</td>


<td>gildan<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>red<br>10m</td>


</tr>
```

This is the code in my PHP if that helps at all. Thanks!

```
    <tr class="' . ($counter++ % 2 ? "odd" : "even") . '">

  <td>Garment:</td>

  <td>' . $result['garment_type'] . '</td>

</tr>
```

Desired code after BR splits

```
<tr class="garment">

  <td>Type:</td>

  <td>gildan<br>white<br>4s<br></td>

</tr>

<tr class="garment">

  <td>Type:</td>

  <td>basic<br>red<br>10m<br></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
<td>' . $result['garment_type'] . '</td>
```

to

```
<td>' . str_replace(' ', '<br />', $result['garment_type'] ) . '</td>
```

This will generate the following HTML:

```
<td>gildan<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>red<br>10m</td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply. Mind if I inbox you for a another questions that's related?

Comment: You're welcome. As far as a follow up question, why not just make a new one here at SO?

Comment: Basically now that they're split. is there anyway to make them they're own TR and TD?

Comment: What would the desired HTML look like?

Comment: One thing I did notice is that added a ton of extra <br> at the end also

Comment: You could use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove the whitespace at the beginning and end of the string

Comment: Putting your variable inside an HTML table cell and then trying to split it into other rows and cells is going to be more of a headache than you want. I'd generate the rows, possible the table, via PHP instead, and split the text as needed.

Comment: Can you show an example of how to use trim on the code you suggested. Pretty sure this can work for me with that for now. Thanks

Comment: Sure, you'd trim the string first, then use it in what I put in my answer. Like `str_replace(' ', '<br />', trim( $result['garment_type'] ) )`

Comment: you could go one step further and help formatting of output with `"<br />\r\n"`

Comment: Hi @MartinBarker what would that do?

Comment: @M.Heredia The only thing that would do is format the output the browser sees so that if you did a "view source" on the page in your browser then the code would have newlines in it. It would have no impact on the layout.

Comment: Still looking for a way to split the results into their own TR and TD. That would be amazing!

Comment: @j08691 i changed to code a bit to look for 2 spaces and then BR instead of just 1 space. Makes things look cleaner. How would I replace the 1 space with a | in the same code?